# MS Access 2013 Concatenate Rows query

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I'm looking for something like **FOR XML PATH ('')** for MS Access.

Since I can only read data but **not modify** the access file/database, everything beyond querying is not an option for me.

A little detail:

My target is to have some query like below but usable for MS Access 2013:

```
SELECT 
    Items.Name, Items.Description , 
    (SELECT ItemValues.Value + ';'
     FROM Itemvalues 
     WHERE Itemvalues.ItemID = [value] 
       AND someOtherConditions
     FOR XML PATH ('') ) AS Values 
FROM 
    Items 
WHERE 
    Items.ID = [value]
```

If the results of ItemValue selection will be like

```
SELECT ItemValues.Value
FROM Itemvalues 
WHERE Itemvalues.ItemID = [value] 
  AND someOtherConditions
```

Output:

```
     itemval1
     property2val
     1234foo
```

And the result of Item Selection will be like

```
SELECT 
    Items.Name, Items.Description 
FROM 
    Items 
WHERE 
    Items.ID = [value]
```

Output:

```
 Testitem | This is a test item
```

I want to have a result row like

```
 Testitem | This is a text test item | itemval1;property2val;1234foo;
```

Thanks your for help

PS: I've seen some other posts about this topic but since those are either many years old or not fit for my situation I'm trying my luck.

Comment: I see that you have added the `.net` tag to this question. What is the environment in which you intend to run this query? C#? VB.NET? ...?

Comment: @GordThompson i will use this query with c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following query with subquery and derived table nested in an aggregate query. Inner query counts number of `ItemValues` per `ItemID` and then outer query conditionally aggregates by `[Name]` and `Description` using calculated count to output a concatenation string of Item's Values.

Unfortunately, you will need to explicitly add `Max(IIF(...)` query statements for each value to be concatenated as below only uses three from your example. See ellipsis.

Please note: this solution assumes you have a primary, autonumber `ID` field in `[ItemValues]` table:

```
SELECT Items.Name, Items.Description,
       Max(IIF(ItemCount=1, t1.Value, NULL)) & ';' &  
       Max(IIF(ItemCount=2, t1.Value, NULL)) & ';' & 
       Max(IIF(ItemCount=3, t1.Value, NULL)) 
       ... As ItemValues       
FROM(
     SELECT Items.Name, Items.Description, t1.Value,
            (SELECT Count(*) FROM ItemValues t2 
             WHERE t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID AND t1.ID >=t2.ID) As ItemCount
     FROM Items INNER JOIN ItemValues t1 ON Items.ID = t1.ItemID
) As derivedTable
GROUP BY Items.Name, Items.Description;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name        Description            ItemValues
Testitem    This is a test item    itemval1;property2val;1234foo
```

By the way, your `Items` and `ItemValues` table seems to resemble the [Entity-Attribute Value (EAV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model where multiple data items and types are stored in a single column. Though it makes for efficient storage at an extreme type of normalization, this model is generally not recommended in database design. See SO posts on the subject: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779252/entity-attribute-value-table-design). Consider a revised table schema to avoid complex queries down the road.

Comment: thanks for you extensively answer  but since I don't know how much values i will get I don't think I can do it this way and I also don't think I'll be allowed to change their database structure when I'm even not allowed to add a module

Comment: You can count the values beforehand and then add the `Max(IIF(...` lines accordingly. Even VBA can help as it can create the querydef, using a loop across items.

Comment: Yes you right I'll query ItemValues first and then build my actual query to get the data. Instead of using loops in loops  ............