# Confused With Database Design For E-Commerce (Product Attributes)

Tags: database-design, attributes, e-commerce, product, catalog

I searched almost all of Stackoverflow for the solution and most of the times the cons took over the pros.

I want to know which is the best database design for implementing product attributes of ecommerce site.

I checked on various approaches

**1) Different tables for each product**.
--> Found out that if i want to have 500 products so that would mean 500 tables.

**2) Semi serialized approach**
--> Would result in inefficient searching

**3) EAV**
--> suggested by many  that it is antipattern and alternatives should be found.

**4) Creating types.**
--> Not suitable for mysql since there is not type like thing here.

I mean how do Amazon,Flipkart,Macys are able to do it.
Yeah one can say they might be using NoSQL Approach now.
But before implementing NoSQL approach, they were still efficient in filtering all these.
Macys.com are appreciated for the efficient filtering design that they have.

Want to implement an approach which would be efficient and changing/migrating it near future should not be an hectic/cumbersome process.

Can anyone suggest the right approach?? 
Does an Relational Solution exists??

-----[EDIT]-------

Does anyone know like how Flipkart or Amazon does this?
Is it recommended to use semi structured approach??

Using XML file to store attributes

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779252/entity-attribute-value-table-design/11972029#11972029