# How to index dynamically generated nested JSON column in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I had run in an case where I need some help, I have a web application where admin can create forms from the dashboard, each form has **fields** and **properties** where **fields** consists of 
`image, name, type, required, public` 
and **properties** consists of only name

So I created the tables as below:

forms_table:

```
ID | Name | status
```

forms_fields_table

```
ID | form_id | name | slug | type | options | required
```

forms_properties

```
ID | form_id | name | slug
```

And on the other side other users can create a real-estate where they will have to fill the data of the real-estate category selected form, So i save filled form data in a column in real-estate table

the data saved like this

```
[
  {slug_value}: {
    "name": "xxxx",
    "value": "xxxx",
    "slug": "ssss",
    "value": 42
  },
  {slug_value}: {
    "name": "yyy",
    "value": "yyy",
    "slug": "aaaa",
    "value": 42
  },
]
```

where all these data are dynamic and the key of each json is the same as slug, and the user should be able to filter the real-estates by these dynamic data by slug and value.

So the question comes here, I know that I can filter data by nested JSON like this : `DB::table('realestates')->where('attributes->{slug_name}->value', 'red')->get();` but I didn't find a way to index dynamic nested JSON so it will take some time in filtering process.

And as I was thinking, it came to my mind what if I store these dynamic data as string and filter the string like this `attributes = "value":"search_query"` but I don't want to change the structure for nothing.

**I'm using laravel**

Comment: What MySQL likes: structured data, e.g. tables with proper relations, fixed columns, one value per column and every information stored once (aka normalized data). You have dynamic forms and storing data of those virtual tables in a dynamic json structure. That's flexible, but won't be fast, as MySQL cannot use the tools a relational database provides for structured data, e.g. indexes. A compromise (apart from using a different dbms) might be to use an eav-model, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779252), it's what you would end up with if you pursue your idea in your last sentence.

Comment: Are the possible values of `slug_value` limited?

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for your response, I read your reference but actually there are a lot of things that I didn't fully understood. I will try to search more. thanks again

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir unfortunately no :(

Comment: The only possible way I see: After a few weeks/months of people using your app, you analyze the slugs and look at the most popular ones. Then you add indexes for these slugs.

Comment: Thank you @JonasStaudenmeir, I think that is the only solution right now, Will try to search more.